# Custom HTTPBinding for HTTP Component

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to throw an exception if HTTP response code is anything other than 200 or 201. I tried to override http4.DefaultHttpBinding, but the class is never getting called. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public class CustomHttpBinding extends org.apache.camel.component.http4.DefaultHttpBinding {

Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CustomHttpBinding.class);
private static final Integer HTTP_OK = 200;
private static final Integer HTTP_CREATED = 201;

@Override
public void doWriteResponse(Message message, HttpServletResponse response, Exchange exchange) throws IOException {
    Integer httpResponseCode = message.getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, Integer.class);

    if(!httpResponseCode.equals(HTTP_OK) && !httpResponseCode.equals(HTTP_CREATED) ) {
        throw new IOException("HTTP error code for HLR response is " + httpResponseCode);
    } 
    else {
        super.doWriteResponse(message, response, exchange);
    }
 }
}
```

In xml:

```
<bean id="customHttpBinding" class="com.test.response.CustomHttpBinding" />

<endpoint uri="http4:${http.url.1}?httpBinding=#customHttpBinding&amp;httpClient.socketTimeout=${http.notificationTimeout}" id="http4.1.to"/>
```

Comment: I am not an expert in Camel, but I would guess that you have a configuration problem in your XML.

Answer (score 0):

If the [http response code is 300+](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html#HTTP4-Responsecode), the binding will throw exception before it calls `doWriteResponse(...)`. Try overriding `writeResponse(...)` in your custom binding, and verify that your binding is used.

Comment: Thanks for the response. HTTP response code is 299. Overriding writeResponse(...) also didn't make any difference. CustomHttpBinding class or overridden method never gets called.

Comment: Do you see the HTTP 299 from logging of the `DefaultHttpBinding`? Next thing I would try is using the custom binding from Java DSL and see if it is XML problem, or different configuration problem.