# How to catch in Apache Camel route the JsonParseException during Jackson marshaling?

Tags: java, json, exception, jackson, apache-camel

I send over HTTP-POST an **invalid** JSON-body to my Camel-Spark-REST component. On my Camel route, the JSON-body will be transformed (marshaling) from JSON to an Java object with the Jackson library. The marshaling fails, because of the invalid JSON-body. With the camel doTry/doCatch elements i try to catch the exceptions and handle them by my own. This looks like this:

```
rest("/v1/users")
    .consumes("application/json")
    .produces("application/json")
.post("/insert")
.to("direct:restInput");

from("direct:restInput")
.doTry()
    .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
    [...]
    .process(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            //throw new JsonParseException(null, "");
       }
    })
    [...]
.doCatch(JsonParseException.class)
    .process(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("JsonParseException occured");
       }
    })
.doCatch(Exception.class)
    .process(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Exception occured");
       }
    })
.end()
.marshal();
```

If there is an invalid JSON-body, the JsonParseException will be thrown by the Jackson marshaler. As you can see above, i try to catch the JsonParseException exception and it should output on my console `JsonParseException occured`.

But instead the exception is **not catched** and i get the full stacktrace on my console:

```
Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route4            ] [route4            ] [spark-rest://post:v1/users/insert?accept=application%2Fjson                   ] [        42]
[route4            ] [restBinding4      ] [                                                                              ] [        39]

Stacktrace
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate Array entries
     at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@1aa6eb2; line: 23, column: 17]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702) ~[jackson-core-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558) ~[jackson-core-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:456) ~[jackson-core-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:761) ~[jackson-core-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.mapArray(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:594) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:510) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2899) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat.unmarshal(JacksonDataFormat.java:172) ~[camel-jackson-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:69) ~[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
        at org.apache.camel.component.rest.RestConsumerBindingProcessor.process(RestConsumerBindingProcessor.java:189) ~[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77) ~[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542) [camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) [camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120) [camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83) [camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) [camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97) [camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
        at org.apache.camel.component.sparkrest.CamelSparkRoute.handle(CamelSparkRoute.java:46) [camel-spark-rest-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
        at spark.RouteImpl$1.handle(RouteImpl.java:58) [spark-core-2.3.jar:?]
        at spark.webserver.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:162) [spark-core-2.3.jar:?]
        at spark.webserver.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:61) [spark-core-2.3.jar:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544) [jetty-io-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_101]
```

Depending on my tests, this happens on the `.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)` part. If i send a valid JSON-body and throw the JsonParseException manually in the first processor (see the comment line), then the exception will be catched. The `Exception.class` catch block will also never be called, so it could be excluded, that i try to catch the "wrong" exception. Is there an opportunity to catch the exception out of the Jackson marshaler or is there a Camel component which checks the JSON-body, if it is well formed, which i can put infront of the marshaler?

Comment: Are you sure the exception is raised on the line  `.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)`? I don't know the spark-rest endpoint, but when using a jetty endpoint with the REST DSL the `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException` is raised in the endpoint itself. Not in a subsequent marshalling step. Next to the stacktrace you should also see the message history in the log. Can you post that as well and/or check the history actually contains the marshalling step?

Comment: You are right @Ralf, i checked the history and it happens in the restBinding. I completely ignored that part, I'm sorry. But it is not possible to put the "doTry/doCatch" part earlier before the .post("...") part. So, i cannot use doTry/doCatch or how did you solve this case? Did you use onException instead?

Comment: Thank you @Ralf, with onException(JsonParseException.class).handled(true).to("..."); in global it works. If you want to post your comment as anwser, i will accept it as "best answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception might be thrown in the endpoint, not in your marshalling step. I don't know the spart-rest endpoint, but with the Jetty endpoint and the REST DSL the marshalling error is thrown in the Jetty endpoint itself. In addition to the stack trace Camel should have logged the message history as well. You can verify in the history whether the marshalling step was executed at all.

```
2017-01-19 09:11:28,040 | ERROR | qtp762554626-172 | DefaultErrorHandler              | 75 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.3 |  | Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-Ralfs-MacBook-Pro-local-60691-1484813099793-0-2 on ExchangeId: ID-Ralfs-MacBook-Pro-local-60691-1484813099793-0-1). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('n' (code 110)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@49828827; line: 33, column: 6]

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8282/some/path?httpMethodRestrict=PUT   ] [        15]
[route1            ] [restBinding1      ] [                                                                              ] [        12]

Exchange
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
    Id                  ID-Ralfs-MacBook-Pro-local-60691-1484813099793-0-1
    ExchangePattern     InOut

[..]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('n' (code 110)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@49828827; line: 33, column: 6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1581)[55:com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core:2.6.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:533)[55:com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core:2.6.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:462)[55:com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core:2.6.3]
[..]
```

If the exception is indeed thrown on the endpoint then your options for custom error handling depend on the kind of error handling you'd like to do.

As you suggested yourself you can use a global `onException` handler to use a processor for your error handling.
If all you want is to control the kind of error message and http response code the client receives, then it might be easier to provide your own http binding or request/response handling strategy. Again I don't know the spark-rest endpoint, but with Jetty you'd provide your own implementation of a http binding like so:

```
public class JettyNoStacktraceHttpBinding extends JettyRestHttpBinding {

    private static final int BAD_REQUEST = 400;

    @Override
    public void doWriteExceptionResponse(Throwable exception, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws java.io.IOException {
        if (exception instanceof JsonParseException) {
            response.setStatus(BAD_REQUEST);

            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
            pw.print(exception.getMessage());
            pw.flush();
        }
    }

}


<restConfiguration contextPath="/some/path" component="jetty" scheme="http" host="0.0.0.0" port="8282" bindingMode="json">
    <endpointProperty key="httpBindingRef" value="jettyNoStackTraceHTTPBinding" />
<!-- ... -->
</restConfiguration>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ralf. The onException part works fine. I also tried your request/response handler. I searched for an abstract class instead of Jetty and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006284/custom-httpbinding-for-http-component) and [this](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html) which says, there should be in org.apache.camel.component.http4 DefaultHttpBinding or HttpBinding. But in Camel 2.17.3/2.18.0 it is missing. I found it in 2.15.0. Did they remove it and forgot to update docu? If yes, whats the alternative now? If you don`t know it, i can ask another question.

Comment: @Zeussi, better to ask a new question.